# Whats faster? Get a null record or check existence?

Tags: java, aerospike, nosql

I have a timeseries lookup. I am currently building and requesting the corresponding keys even if they don't exist (getting a null record) in a span of time. Is there a better way to do it? Checking existence of the key, prior to the get for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Just get the records you need.**

My rule of thumb is this: "If you really only need to know if the key exists, then just check that.  However, if the first thing you're going to do for a key that exists is to get the value, then just get the values."

In order to check if it exists, it has to do a lookup on the key.  The only difference between this and returning the value is actually retrieving the value.  A "get" operation would have to do the same lookup.  If the value is none, then there is no additional overhead required to return a value, except a couple extra bytes to store a "null" instead of `false`.  However, if you only need to know the key exists, then there's no reason to return the whole contents if it does.